# Ubuntu 18.04 cron.hourly script not running

Tags: bash, cron, ubuntu-18.04

I have a script in /etc/cron.hourly that I want to run.
The script is something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

echo "Doing something"
eval $(do_something)
exec >> /tmp/log 2>&1
```

and

```
$ ls /etc/cron.hourly
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug  1 11:31 ./
drwxr-xr-x 94 root root 4096 Aug  1 11:37 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  102 Nov 16  2017 .placeholder
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  131 Aug  1 11:31 workSomeThing*
```

and

```
$ sudo run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
```

Shows that it runs correctly.

But the script doesn't run by it self every hour...

Edit:

```
# cat /etc/crontab
17 *    * * *   root cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

and

```
# sudo systemctl status cron.service 
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-07-25 11:03:27 UTC; 1 weeks 0 days ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 719 (cron)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 1152)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           └─719 /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

Comment: Do you have the entry for cron.hourlyin your `/etc/crontab`?

Comment: I guessed that it came pre configured for this... but I think it has them:
( from /etc/crontab)
17 * * * * root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6 * * * root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6 * * 7 root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6 1 * * root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )

Comment: Please don't add information as comments, edit your question instead. This is unreadable here. But it seems like it is there, yes. Is your crond running?

Comment: I assume you mean cron.service in systemd, yes it is.

Comment: Well, if no error shows up in the system logs I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I think the script may be wrong or something... thanks for your help.

Comment: Is that `exec >> /tmp/log 2>&1` command really at the end of the script? If so, that explains why you aren't getting output in /tmp/log. Try putting it at the beginning of the script.